# What is the most minimal set of babel plugins needed to transpile for Node 6

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

In my Node app I use `import`, arrow functions, the spread operator, object destructuring, `let`, and `const`.

In my `package.json` I include the following

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=6.9.4",
  "npm": "^3"
},
```

as well as

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "node6",
    "stage-0"
  ]
},
```

and

```
"scripts": {
  "clean": "rm -rf bin/",
  "start": "node bin/index.js",
  "babel": "babel src --out-dir bin",
  "build": "npm run clean && npm run babel",
  "dev": "babel-node src/index.js",
  "test": "find ./test -name '*_spec.js' | NODE_ENV=test xargs mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js"
},
```

The code works and is transpliled but I've noticed that, looking at the transpiled files, it's converting `let` to `var`, which seems pointless given Node 6.9.4 fully supports the use of `let` natively.

What is the most minimal set of babel plugins that will allow my code to run under Node 6.9.4 or better and will maximise use of its native language features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest option would be to use https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env. So you can install that and then in your Babel config do

```
{
  presets: [['env', {targets: {node: true}}]]
}
```

and it will automatically configure the plugins for your current Node version.

Comment: Interesting and very cool project.  I tried it as suggested and now babel converts both `const` and `let` to `var` which seems like a retrograde step. I've had a few goes at fine-tuning it but it's still not giving me `let`

Comment: Ugh, I typoed the config, it's `targets:`, not `target:`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the set of language features you mention, I don't think you need `stage-0`.

You might consider just using [`babel-preset-es2015`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/), which supports `arrow-functions`, `destructuring`, `import` statements and the `spread` operator for `Array` ([Object rest/spread](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread) still requires a [separate plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) as it's only [stage-3](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-3/) at the time of this writing).

TL;DR; - For what you've described, I think you can probably just use:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Comment: In the next sentence you referred to the object spread syntax, not to the destructuring.

Comment: Oh jeeze - you're totally right. I'm all fuddled - thanks for the catch.

Comment: I needed `stage-0` for the spread operator and modules. `node6` supersedes the `es2015`.

Comment: @DaveSag unless there is no "spread operator and modules" in the stage-0

Comment: @zerkms Hmm weird, previously if I removed `stage-0` the `import x from 'x'` lines remained in the built code and Node 6.9.4 complains. But I just tried it again and it works fine. My bad.

Comment: so so far the best translation comes from `"presets": ["node6"]` but it's still converting `let` to `var`